# Blank String added in a Integer array when sending from a java socket

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, objectoutputstream

I am trying to send an integer array using ObjectOutputStream and WriteObject method from a client and receiving the array from the server. Here is Client and Server code respectively:

Client:

```
int numberArray [] = new int[]{3,6,1,5,8};
ObjectOutputStream os =new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
os.writeObject(numberArray);
```

Server:

```
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
int[] Array = (int[])is.readObject();
for (int e : Array) {
 System.out.print(e + " ");
}
```

The client can send the array successfully. However, when I am trying to read the array the following error occurs and program exits:

```
3 6 1 5 8 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at testserver.TestServer.main(TestServer.java:73)
Java Result: 1
```

Please can anybody tell me where I am doing the wrong??

Comment: Is it possible for you to post more code? I tested what you have so far and do not get any exceptions.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce this. It looks like you're calling `parseInt` from your code, but you haven't shown that... (I'm not quite sure how you got 5 upvotes from the question in its current from...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what weird happened in my android studio or Netbeans. I have written the code in a fresh new project and now it's working !!!!
Here is my complete code. For the sack of simplicity last time I didn't post the whole code.

However, in the client code if I use only print method there is no output in the console, but if I use println method then contents of the array are printled in the console. Can anybody explain why this is happening??

Server

```
package testserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TestServer {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerSocket listener;
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        listener = new ServerSocket(9090,50,addr);        
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for Client...!!!");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                try {
                    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    int[] Array = (int[])is.readObject();
                    for (int e : Array) {
                        System.out.print(e + " ");
                    }

                    ObjectOutputStream os =new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeObject(Array);
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
package com.example.asus.clientwitharray;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response ="";
    TextView textResponse;

    Client(String addr, int port, TextView textResponse) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        this.textResponse = textResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            int numberArray [] = new int[]{2,4,6,1,9};
            ObjectOutputStream os =new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            os.writeObject(numberArray);

            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            int[] Arr = (int[])is.readObject();
            for (int e : Arr) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```